# Ansible time Conversion

Tags: date, time, ansible

I am comparing the last access time of a file with a file_date variable.
Vars:

```
file_date: '2013-12-12 14:35:02'
```

Playbook:

```
  - name: set fact
    set_fact:
      time: "{{ (file_date|to_datetime).strftime('%s') }}"
```

Output shows as below:

```
ok: <server> {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "time": "1386876902"
    }, 
    "changed": false
}
```

But the last access time from win_stat output is

```
"lastwritetime": 1386858902.
```

There is slight difference because of the timezone. I need to subtract some value from time or change the timezone. Kindly advice how this can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would save that lastwritetime from win_stat to a register, and then use set_fact to perform the math operation on it.

```
- set_fact:
    math_time: "{{ register_name.lastwritetime - 18000 }}"
```

Based on your output this should work, seeing as there are no quotes around the number.  But if its getting returned as a string, just use a jinja filter to recast it as an integer and it should still work.

```
- set_fact:
    math_time: "{{ register_name.lastwritetime|int - 18000 }}"
```